# Try using sample Group info Encounter AttributeError about module 'pulp'

Tags: snakemake

**Snakemake version**
`5.25.0`

**Describe the bug**
I am trying construct a rule by group `merge`-like operation . dry-run is ok, but `snakemake -p -j1` failed with this ERROR
`AttributeError: module 'pulp' has no attribute 'apis'`

**Logs**

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        2       IDRPeakMerge
        1       all
        3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 735, in snakemake
    keepincomplete=keep_incomplete,
  File ".../miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 972, in execute
    success = scheduler.schedule()
  File ".../miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 406, in schedule
    else self.job_selector_ilp(needrun)
  File ".../miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 616, in job_selector_ilp
    if pulp.apis.LpSolverDefault is None:
AttributeError: module 'pulp' has no attribute 'apis'
```

**Minimal example**

```
SAMPLES = {
    'group1':["SRR1552451","SRR1552453","ERR127302"],
    'group2':["ERR127302","SRR1552452"]
}

rule all:
    input:
        expand('idr/{group}.idr.peak',group=list(SAMPLES.keys()))

rule IDRPeakMerge:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: expand('macs2/{sample}.summits.bed', sample=SAMPLES[wildcards.group]) 
    output:
        'idr/{group}.idr.peak'
    run:
        shell("head -n 1 {input}  >> {output} ")
```

**Additional context**
file tree

```
s03peaks
├── idr
└── macs2
    ├── ERR127302.summits.bed
    ├── SRR1552451.summits.bed
    ├── SRR1552452.summits.bed
    └── SRR1552453.summits.bed
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to integrate group information? And is there any error in Minimal example?    (I failed to debug codes above ) @DmitryKuzminov

Comment: Did you try on a different machine? The error looks like a problem with Python installation.

Comment: I haven't yet. But if I use common list to recorded the sample without group information, snakemake works well. So I guess  both python and  snakemake  have been installed  in right way @DmitryKuzminov

Comment: I don't see any issue on my version of Snakemake. Try to reinstall or check on another machine.